# StringBuilder new line add 2 more characters

Tags: c#, newline, stringbuilder

I need to generate a file with 240 characters per line, but when I use AppendLine he adds 2 more characters causing my line is 242 characteres, could help me?

P.S: I've tried using Enviroment.Newline and "\ n"

Comment: that's \r\n sequence that gets added at the end of the line.

Comment: That's the standard windows text line terminator characters. Without them the line would just continue on.

Comment: "\r\n" gave me the same result

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Its a simple code like var1 + var 2 + var 2.... + Enviroment.NewLine

Comment: those two extra characters are not part of the line, they are what makes it a line. are you sure you have a problem?? how does it show???

Comment: You're right Taw, I was trying to check using length but looking at my file it really is 240 characters, thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

AppendLine appends Environment.NewLine. You should probably wrap at

```
int charCountBeforeNewLine = 240 - Environment.NewLine.Length;

Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine.Length); // 2
```

Comment: I can't do that cause it is bank file and I have to respect field position in my file